# node mocha async hooks not working?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Ok so I'm obviously new to mocha. From my understanding after reading the docs and googling this should work but it isn't:

```
describe("Check before", function(){

    var beforeCalled = false;
    before(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            beforeCalled = true;
            done();
        }, 150);
    });

    it("should run after before called", function(){
        expect(beforeCalled).to.equal(true);
    })
})
```

the `it` part doesn't wait for 'before' to finish and is called. Maybe I read the docs wrong or I'm missing something, not sure.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `done` callback must be in the function signature for mocha to wait.

```
before(function(done){
    setTimeout(function() {
        beforeCalled = true;
        done();
    }, 150);
});
```

I've got into the habit of always using `done` when there are mixed synchronous and async tests. Mocha can finish as if no tests have failed if you forget one async `done` on an `it`.

Comment: Oh man I can't believe I missed that. URGH. So much time wasted for nothing.. Need to look more closely at sample codes :/... Thank you so much!